# React.js - scroll is inactive when soft keyboard is open (hiding the views)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullscreen, progressive-web-apps

I am using `requestFullscreen()` in javascript to provide a full screen PWA experience to my user but the problem that I am facing is when a user toggles the keyboard on a mobile device, the screen is not scrollable and the user has to close the keyboard in order to fill in the remaining information. This is not good for my UX and I would like to keep scrolling active just like it is without the full screen mode.

Any suggestions are welcome.

//for full screen mode

```
addEventListenerOnce( document.body, "click", function(e) {
        var el = document.documentElement;
        if(el.requestFullscreen) {
            rfs = el.requestFullscreen;
        } else if(el.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            rfs = el.mozRequestFullScreen;
        } else if(el.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            rfs = el.webkitRequestFullscreen;
        } else if(el.msRequestFullscreen) {
            rfs =el.msRequestFullscreen;
        }    
        rfs.call(el);
    });
```

I've tried a lot of `JS` to change scroll position but nothing seems to work in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html). You may use:

```
keyboardDismissMode?: PropTypes.oneOf([
  'none', // default
  'interactive',
  'on-drag',
]) #
```

- Determines whether the keyboard gets dismissed in response to a drag. `- 'none'` (the default), drags do not dismiss the keyboard. `- 'on-drag'`, the keyboard is dismissed when a drag begins. `- 'interactive'`, the keyboard is dismissed interactively with the drag and moves in synchrony with the touch; dragging upwards cancels the dismissal.

Or

```
keyboardShouldPersistTaps?: PropTypes.oneOf([
  'always', 
  'never', 
  'handled', 
  false, 
  true
]) #
```

- Determines when the keyboard should stay visible after a tap.

  - `'never'` (the default), tapping outside of the focused text input when the keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When this happens, children won't receive the tap.
  - `'always'`, the keyboard will not dismiss automatically, and the scroll view will not catch taps, but children of the scroll view can catch taps.
  - `'handled'`, the keyboard will not dismiss automatically when the tap was handled by a children, (or captured by an ancestor).
  - `false`, deprecated, use `'never'` instead
  - `true`, deprecated, use `'always'` instead

Here a sample code: [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view). You can use the `KeyboardAwareScrollView` or the `KeyboardAwareListView` components. Both accept `ScrollView` and `ListView` default props and implements a custom `KeyboardAwareMixin` to handle keyboard appearance. The mixin is also available if you want to use it in any other component.

Comment: Can I use `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` for react web?